# LLVM & Clang++ AST

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Установил Clang по [гайду](http://blog.johannesmp.com/2015/09/01/installing-clang-on-windows-pt2/)
и обнаружил, что LLVM\include нет папок clang и llvm (есть clang-с и llvm-с)

Соответственно при попытке использовать ([пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320074/)):

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <clang/AST/Decl.h>
#include "clang/AST/DeclBase.h"
#include "clang/AST/Expr.h"
```

получаю ошибку:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM>clang++ F:\Checker\main.cpp -o F:\Checker\main.exe -
I"C:\Program Files\LLVM\include" -I"C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib " -
L"C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib" -llibclang
F:\Checker\main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'clang/AST/Decl.h' file not found
#include <clang/AST/Decl.h>
     ^
1 error generated.

C:\Program Files\LLVM>
```

Вопрос, где взять эти папки?Копировать из исходников?
Или надо каким-то другим способом ставить clang?

Comment: А откуда вы взяли `clang/AST/Expr.h`? В примере по ссылке такого нету.

Comment: В исходниках на гитхабе есть https://github.com/arktur04/llvm-clang-c-util-example/blob/master/clang-c-ast.cpp

Comment: Вы пробовали установить clang по [мануалу с llvm.org](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Среди интерфейсов Clang, которые предлагает [документация](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html), C++ API нет, поскольку он не стабилен и не гарантирует обратную совместимость. Если хочется использовать именно его, нужно скачать исходники llvm+clang и строить вручную.