# Использование библиотеки AST для clang проекта

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Пытаюсь в проекте использовать данные заголовки после сборки llvm из исходников в ubuntu

`#include <clang-c/Index.h>`

`#include <clang/AST/Decl.h>`

`#include "clang/AST/DeclBase.h"`

`#include "clang/AST/Expr.h"`

Получаю ошибку, что невозможно подключить
Вопрос где они должны быть?в папке собранного llvm или в папке с исходниками llvm?

Comment: они должны быть в {prefix}/include, где prefix — это префикс, куда установлен llvm/clang.

Comment: /home/user/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/lib/ и /home/user/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/bin/ это все что есть после сборки, ну и плюс исходники

Comment: как именно собирал? (с точностью до команд и каталогов в которых они запускались)

Comment: В точности по гайду 
http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.ru/2012/12/building-llvm-32-from-source.html

Comment: он довольно древний лучше им не пользоваться... им даже в те времена пользоваться стоило с большой осторожностью: `configure` ни когда не был предпочтительным способом конфигурации, а на данный момент вообще выпилен... конфигурируй `cmake`'ом и не забудь указать `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/to/put//my/stuff`. и после сборки выполнить `make install`..

Comment: пытался несколько раз собрать, качал и через свн и через гит, конфигурировал `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm` по примеру https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html, но либо получал ошибку (ошибка выполнения рецепта), либо не хватало места на диске, папка вырастала почти до 40гб, так и должно быть?

Comment: В итоге уcтановил clang через apt install, либы таким же образом (кроме clang-tools-5.0), нашел все необходимые заголовки и либы, но теперь имею вот такую ошибку clang++-5.0 main.cpp -o main -I/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/include/ -L/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/lib/ -lclang -std=c++14
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-60cc2a.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «_ZN4llvm24DisableABIBreakingChecksE@@LLVM_5.0»
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) это ошибка порядка линковки библиотек?

Comment: гм... по ошибкам сложно что-то сказать — на каждую ошибку желателен полный лог сборки, конфигурации, а также CMakeCache.txt... + информация о конфигурации системы (версии libc, компилятора итп...), а также точном происхождении исходников...  Каталоги сборки особо разрастаться не должны — гигабайт 10 должно хватать... Но для уменьшения размера и времени сборки я бы попробовал ограничить целевые системы (тебе же вряд ли нужен генератор кода для какого-нибудь mips'а или nvptx'а или и то и другое одновременно).

Comment: Сборку из исходников отложил, ограничился apt install, к тому же мне действительно ничего лишнего не надо, хочется попробовать поработать с AST через API clang. Система Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64 разряда, clang-5.0. (отсюда https://apt.llvm.org/), скомпилировать (`clang++-5.0 main.cpp -o main -I/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/include/ -L/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/lib/ -lclang -LLVM-5.0 -std=c++14`) пытаюсь пример https://github.com/arktur04/llvm-clang-c-util-example/blob/master/clang-c-ast.cpp , `.../libLLVM-5.0.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing...` библиотека  libLLVM-5.0.so имеется, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `-lclangAST` не хватает..

Comment: Итог: `clang++-5.0 main.cpp -o main -I/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/include/ -L/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/lib/ -lclang -lclangCodeGen -lclangARCMigrate -lclangIndex -lclangFormat -lclangTooling -lclangToolingCore -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangRewrite -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangSerialization -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangAnalysis -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic -std=c++14
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/llvm-5.0/lib//libclangAST.a(ExprConstant.cpp.o): неопределённая ссылка на символ «_ZNK4llvm5APInt25countTrailingOnesSlowCaseEv@@LLVM_5.0»`

Comment: + `//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: теперь `-lLLVMSupport`... Вот небольшой наколеночный скриптик для поиска, где объявлен недостающий символ: https://paste.pound-python.org/show/OjH3ZgTLismqtMqjqKbd/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вопрос решился добавлением -lLLVM-5.0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [LLVM & Clang++ AST](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790257/llvm-clang-ast)